# Symfony 4 : Controller requires that you provide a value for the "$id" argument

Tags: symfony4

I have a page with a list of projects. When you click on one project, you should arrive on a "project_detail" page.

Here is my MainController with the route to project_detail :

```
 /**
 * @Route("/project_detail/{$id}", name="project_detail")
 */
public function project_detail($id)
{
    $current_project = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(Project::class)
        ->find($id);

    return $this->render('main/project_detail.html.twig', [
        'current_project' => $current_project,
    ]);
}
```

And here is my template project_list, with the link to the "project_detail" page :

```
<a href="{{ path('project_detail', {'id':project.id }) }}">
    <div>...</div>
</a>
```

I obtain this link by clicking on it: website/project_detail/%7B%24id%7D?**id=1**

So I suppose that it understands that the page should show the project which have the id number 1. However, it keeps displaying this error : **Controller "App\Controller\MainController::project_detail()" requires that you provide a value for the "$id" argument.**

Do you have any idea of what I'm doing wrong ?

Thank you for your time,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your annotation to this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/project_detail/{id}", name="project_detail")
 */
```

The change is to drop the `$` in front of the `id` variable.

Answer (score 2):

The variable you pass is "current_project" and this means you need to change:

```
<a href="{{ path('project_detail', {'id':project.id }) }}">
    <div>...</div>
</a>
```

to

```
<a href="{{ path('project_detail', {'id':current_project.id }) }}">
    <div>...</div>
</a>
```

And remember also to fix this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/project_detail/{$id}", name="project_detail")
 */
```

with this

```
/**
 * @Route("/project_detail/{id}", name="project_detail")
 */
```

Comment: You make a good point about `current_project` passed from the controller vs `project` as used by the OP, but since we haven't seen the rest of the twig script this may or may not be a problem. For example, the `<a>` tag with `project.id` could be in the middle of a loop through all projects, like `{% for project in projects %} ... ` for example. I'm just pointing out that these two are not necessarily linked for anyone reading this in the future.